# Failing to programmatically add a not null validator to a WPF ComboBox

Tags: wpf

Why is this failing?

I have a UserControl which contains a ComboBox.

I have a property called "Mandatory" with which that user can add validation in case no choice is made.

So I have this in the user control:

```
public static DependencyProperty MandatoryProperty
  = DependencyProperty.Register("Mandatory", typeof(bool), typeof(CountyPicker),
    new PropertyMetadata((bool)false, OnChangedMandatoryByBinding));

private static void OnChangedMandatoryByBinding
  (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  var value = (bool)e.NewValue;

  ((CountyPicker)d).OnChangedMandatoryByBinding(value);
}

public bool Mandatory
{
  get { return (bool)GetValue(MandatoryProperty); }
  set { SetValue(MandatoryProperty, value); }
}

public void OnChangedMandatoryByBinding(bool value)
{
  var binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding
    (TheComboBox, ComboBox.SelectedItemProperty);

  binding.ValidationRules.Clear();

  if (value == true) // strange that I need this without getting a warning
  {
    binding.ValidationRules.Add(new NotNullValidator());
  }
}
```

The xaml contains:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Foo.Controls.Pickers.CountyPicker"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ComboBox Name="TheComboBox"
      KeyDown="TheComboBox_KeyDown"
      SelectedItem="{Binding County,Mode=TwoWay}" />
</UserControl>
```

But although the value of Mandatory is set like this:

```
<p:CountyPicker Mandatory="True"
  CountyCode="{Binding customer.CountyCode, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

...no validation seems to be made. I have put a breakpoint in the NotNullValidator:s Validate method, but thats not hit.

Comment: does `binding.ValidationRules.Add(new NotNullValidator());` ever get called?

Comment: Yes, I have written to the console in the constructor of NotNullValidator, forgot to mention!